# V-for loop in vuejs doesn't return anything

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying this vuejs app within laravel, Its a simple app where I'm fetching data and then trying to display it with laravel, here's my messages.vue

> Messages.vue

```
<template lang="html">
<div id="frame2">
  <div  id="contacts">
    <ul>
      <div v-for="privsteMsg in privsteMsgs">
        <li class="contact">
          <div class="wrap">
            <span class="contact-status online"></span>
            <img :src="'/uploads/imgs/avatars/' + privsteMsg.avatar">
            <div class="meta">
              <p class="name">{{privsteMsg.name}}</p>
              <p class="preview">Hey it's me</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
      </div>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>

</template>
<script>
export default {
  props: ['userid'],
  data() {
    return {
      privsteMsgs: [],
      bUrl1: 'http://test.app:8000',
    }
  },

  ready: function(){
    this.created();
  },

  created(){
    axios.get(this.bUrl1 + '/api/getMessages')
      .then(response => {
        app.privsteMsgs = response.data; //we are putting data into our posts array
        console.log(app.privsteMsgs);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error); // run if we have error
      });

  },

}
</script>
```

the weird is that the `console.log(app.privsteMsgs);` returns data normally but when I try to loop through it nothing shows as if there's no data.

Comment: What is your `app` variable?

Comment: I'm sorry but what app variable?

Comment: `app.privsteMsgs`. How do you define `app`? Should it be `this.privsteMsgs=...`

Comment: In your code, you did it like ``app.privateMsgs`` but where is your ``app`` variable declared?

Comment: Well that's embarassing, haven't changed that since I changed the files, thank you guys

Answer (score 0):

You have declared app variable but its not defined. replace app variable with this e.g

```
created(){
        let _this = this
        axios.get(this.bUrl1 + '/api/getMessages')
          .then(response => {
            _this.privsteMsgs = response.data; //we are putting data into our posts array
            console.log(_this.privsteMsgs);
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error); // run if we have error
          });

      }
```